# Does SVM have regularization built in (besides the regularization parameter C)?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

A common way of regularization is to minimize the sum of the error function and the norm of the weights vector multiplied by the regularization parameter. Many a time, this has the effect of choosing important features while ignoring the unimportant ones.

The SVM primal form minimizes [image]. This suggests that the aforementioned regularization is built into SVM. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

SVMs are typically formulated as classifiers optimizing [the margin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_(machine_learning)). Which can be shown to be equivalent to the l2 regularization term you show in the question.

For a detailed discussion, see e.g. [Bishop](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) Chapter 7.